# jquery.balloon.js: выводить contents+title

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как используя jquery.balloon.js вывести содержимое title и contents?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('div').balloon({            
        position:"bottom",
        html: true, 
        contents: "Hello " + title выбранного элемента
    });
});
```

Comment: а `title` - это атрибут `title=""`?

Comment: До .balloon() тайтлы элементов заполняются. Т.е. title!=""

Comment: попробуйте `contents: "hello "+this.title` или `contents: "hello "+$(this).attr('title')`

Comment: В обоих случаях берется document.title вместо title элемента